# What constitutes a user in Oracle (and in DBs in general) in relation to transactions?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, rdbms

I usually see references to locks being held by a user. Does this mean a single connection, all logged in connections by a user account, etc...?

How does this apply to Oracle and DBs in general?

If it applies to more than one connection, wouldn't people see data while it's being modified?

How does this apply to JDBC?

```
You can see any changes you have made during the transaction by querying the modified tables, but other users cannot see the changes. After you commit the transaction, the changes are visible to other users' statements that execute after the commit.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means a specific user session. If you look at the `DBA_LOCKS` table you'll see a `session_id` column, which relates to `v$session` and represents a single user session (i.e. connection), not all sessions for the user ID. The locking mechanisms are explained [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#i5338). You're right, if that was not the case then other sessions/connections for the user would see uncommitted changes, which is never allowed (in Oracle, anyway, but for all RDBMS as far as I'm aware).

For JDBC the same applies, each lock is held by a single connection. If you have a connection pool with multiple open connections against the same user account, changes made using one connection form the pool will not be visible to other connections until they are committed. So, if you're executing multiple statements as part of a logical transaction (in which case hopefully you do not have auto-commit on), you need to keep reusing the same connection for all of them, not fetch a new connection from the pool each time as that may or may not get the same one with the pending changes.

Comment: When a connection is returned to the pool it should commit or rollback the active transaction (just as a normal `Connection.close()` would).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - do you mean there's an in-built mechanism that does that, or that the program should explicitly commit/rollback before releasing?

Comment: A correctly implemented connection pool should take care of that.